# javascript calendar - highlight specific days

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a datepicker javascript calendar that highlights specific holidays with a specific color. 
I need it to highlight the days Wednsday (3) - Saturday (6) as well and am struggling. 
 
Here is the code I am using thus far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
                var SelectedDates = {};

                SelectedDates[new Date('01/01/2014')] = new Date('01/01/2014');
                SelectedDates[new Date('01/02/2014')] = new Date('01/02/2014');
                SelectedDates[new Date('01/03/2014')] = new Date('01/03/2014');

                $('#date1, #date2').datepicker({
                        beforeShowDay: function(date) {
                                var Highlight = SelectedDates[date];
                                if (Highlight) {
                                        return [true, "highlighted", Highlight];
                                }
                                else {
                                        return [true, '', ''];
                                }
                        }
                });

        });

    </script>
```

The CSS looks like this:

```
.highlighted a{background:#f57d31 !important;}
```

And the form looks like this:

```
<input id="date1" name="date1" size="12" type="text" />
```

Please help on the best route to highlight Wednsday (3) - Saturday (6) on entire calendar. 
Thanks~!

Comment: Your example seems to work fine http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/s6X97/ (provided you navigate to 2014).

Comment: It does for those specific dates, but i need to highlight wednesday through saturday as well.

Comment: Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/s6X97/2/?

Comment: Thats it - thank you. Now the client provided a larger break down - those highlighted days w-s days need to be only the month of may -sept. Please advise!

Answer (score 0):

The following highlights Wednesday through Saturday for the months May through September:

```
$('#date1, #date2').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function (date) {
        var day = date.getDay();
        var month = date.getMonth();
        return [(day>=3 && day<=6)&&(month>=4 && month<=8), "highlighted"];
    }
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/s6X97/4/)**